# Laravel Sentry User Model with Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, cartalyst-sentry

I have a User Model:

```
use Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User as SentryModel;

class User extends SentryModel {

    public function raspberries() {
        return $this->hasMany('Raspberry');
    }

}
```

And a SentryModel:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class SentryModel extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

}
```

And a Rasberry Model:

```
class Raspberry extends Eloquent{

    # Relations
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

And now I want select all Rasberries from my logged user:

```
$data = Sentry::getUser()->raspberries()->paginate(10);
```

But this doesn't work, I got error Message:

> BadMethodCallException
>
> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::raspberries()

Why?

Comment: Have you changed the sentry config and let it know which `user` model to use?

Comment: great! I have change now the Sentry Config 'users' from 
`'model' => 'Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User',`
to 
`'model' => 'User',`
and now  it works! Thanks!

Comment: Hey make an answer and accept it so it doesn't float around as an unanswered question